# How to draw a heatmap in Three.js based on time spent per vector3 point data?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I am capturing "time spent per unique coordinate" data from Unity. And then, storing the data in an array with each object having the following type:

```
{
    position: {
      x: 3.17354512,
      y: 2.56866765,
      z: -5.206524,
    },
    time: 0.002090454,
  },
```

I want to generate a heat map in 3D space with a list of such data such that red zones indicate areas where maximum amount of time has been spent and blue zones indicate areas where least amount of time has been spent.

So far I have tried to create a `THREE.Buffergeometry()`, set its positions and color attributes using `THREE.Colors.lerp()` but the results are far from satisfactory. Any help would be appreciated . I am very new to shaders. So, using Shaders would be the last option for me, for now

Comment: Can you show an example of what you're trying to accomplish, and the code you've written that shows the progress you've made, even if it's unsatisfactory?